# Как сделать Floating Action Button из materializecss открытым по дефолту?

Tags: javascript, jquery, materialize-css

Использую FAB из materializecss https://materializecss.com/floating-action-button.html
Кнопки изначально закрыты (скрыты) и открываются только при наведении (hoverEnabled:true) или при клике (hoverEnabled:false).
Есть ли возможность сделать кнопки изначально открытыми, если используется открытие при клике?

Comment: наприммер вызвать метод [.open](https://materializecss.com/floating-action-button.html)

Comment: Моя "функция" 
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.fixed-action-btn');
        var instances = M.FloatingActionButton.init(elems, {
            direction: 'top',
            hoverEnabled: false,
            toolbarEnabled: false,
        });
Вот таким способом не могу сделать почему то
 $(document).ready(function () {
            instances.open();
        })

Comment: Я понял, спасибо!! надо было так $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.fixed-action-btn').floatingActionButton('open');
    })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем вот :D

```
// сама функция
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var elems = document.querySelectorAll('.fixed-action-btn');
    var instances = M.FloatingActionButton.init(elems, {
        direction: 'top',
        hoverEnabled: false,
        toolbarEnabled: false,
    });

});
// открытие при загрузке страницы
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.fixed-action-btn').floatingActionButton('open');
});
```